# Is it still necessary to register custom UITableView cells with iOS 9?

Tags: uitableview, ios9

I have a Storyboard which includes `UITableViews` that have custom cells.

In the past, before using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` I have read that it was good practice to register the custom cell's class with the `UITableView` object.

With iOS 9 and Storyboards, is registering the custom cell classes before using them still good practice/necessary to prevent a crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a storyboard with prototype cells you should not register anything with the same identifier as that will replace the registration made by the storyboard. If you're setting the table / collection view up in code then you need to register the cells.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So then in this case, I can still use the method with "forIndexPath" without expecting the app to crash?

Comment: Yes, either you register in the storyboard or in code, not both